# websocketapp does not use SSL.py send()

Tags: python, ssl, websocket

I am trying to write a `websocket.websocketApp` python code with a host: `wss://demo.ctraderapi.com:5035`.

so far I have this:

```
def on_open(ws):
    print(f"on_open ws={ws}")

    # Create an instance of ProtoOAApplicationAuthReq
    auth_request = ProtoOAAccountAuthReq()
    # Set the client ID and secret
    auth_request.ctidTraderAccountId = 25928084
    auth_request.accessToken = "97RfUCjLnvqM2-v_HzLwRN_-_hUhCLhhq23xxxxxx"
    auth_request.payloadType = ProtoOAPayloadType.PROTO_OA_ACCOUNT_AUTH_REQ
    # # Serialize the message to a string

    msg = ProtoMessage(payload=auth_request.SerializeToString(),
                       clientMsgId="nothing",
                       payloadType=auth_request.payloadType)
    data = msg.SerializeToString()

    # data = sendall(message=auth_request, clientMsgId="web-socket.py")
    ws.send(data)


host = "wss://demo.ctraderapi.com:5035"

ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2 | ssl.OP_NO_COMPRESSION | ssl.OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3 | ssl.OP_SINGLE_DH_USE | ssl.OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE | ssl.OP_NO_TICKET
ssl_context.set_ciphers("TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM8:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM8:DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM8:DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-CCM8:AES256-CCM:AES128-CCM8:AES128-CCM:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA")

web_socket_app = websocket.WebSocketApp(host,
                                        on_message=on_message,
                                        on_error=on_error,
                                        on_close=on_close,
                                        on_open=on_open)

sslopt = {"ssl_context": ssl_context}
web_socket_app.run_forever(sslopt=sslopt)
```

I am not good with SSL, but I spent a long time to try to understand the set_ciphers().

As far as I can see, the `WebSocketApp` becomes `closed` immediately, I'm not sure why.

this is the output:

```
on_open ws=<websocket._app.WebSocketApp object at 0x7f4f28147620>
++Sent raw: b'\x81\xc1\xd2\x86\x9fn\xda0\x8f|\xe1\x8e)~\xc2\x12\\\xc0\xde\x9c\xb6W\xe5\xd4\xf9;\x91\xec\xd3\x00\xa4\xf7\xd2\\\xff\xf0\xc0&\xa8\xca\xe8<\x9c\xd9\xb21\xba\xd3\xf7-\x9e\xee\xf7\x1f\xe0\xb5\xe7\x16\xaa\xfe\xe7\x16\xc8\x81\xf1\x01\xa6\xee\xf6\x00\xb5'
++Sent decoded: fin=1 opcode=1 data=b'\x08\xb6\x10\x123\x08\xb6\x10\x10\x94\xc3\xae\x0c\x1a)97RfUCjLnvqM2-v_HzLwRN_-_hUhCLhhq23xxxxxx\x1a\x07nothing'
++Rcv raw: b'\x88\x05\x03\xe8Bye'
++Rcv decoded: fin=1 opcode=8 data=b'\x03\xe8Bye'
++Sent raw: b'\x88\x82\x97\xe3\xe2\x12\x94\x0b'
++Sent decoded: fin=1 opcode=8 data=b'\x03\xe8'
on_close ws=<websocket._app.WebSocketApp object at 0x7f4f28147620>, status_code=1000, msg=Bye
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=6, family=2, type=1, proto=6, laddr=('192.168.1.192', 41470), raddr=('3.33.208.221', 5035)>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I believe that the `ws.send` should come from SSL.y but does not:

```
    def send(self, buf, flags=0):
        """
        Send data on the connection. NOTE: If you get one of the WantRead,
        WantWrite or WantX509Lookup exceptions on this, you have to call the
        method again with the SAME buffer.

        :param buf: The string, buffer or memoryview to send
        :param flags: (optional) Included for compatibility with the socket
                      API, the value is ignored
        :return: The number of bytes written
        """
```

what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your time.